# ASP.NET application not validating after hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created an ASP.NET application that uses RequieredFieldValidators. It works fine when I run the project from my machine, however when I put the application on the server and host it in IIS, the application stops validating. Any idea how this can be fixed? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: define "stops validating"? are any exceptions thrown or are there errors shown in the event viewer? Can you show your implementation? Is it possible that the page is cached?

Comment: You need to share your piece of code for people to help you to find where there is problem to resolve it.

Comment: Are you using javascript tidbits in your application and one of them is having an error and that causes everything to stop?

Comment: While testing the requiredFieldValidators it worked fine. So, if data wasn't entered in the field, it will tell you that the field was required. After I finished the application I hosted it in a test server in IIS and it still checked for required fields. But when I hosted in IIS in the live server then the form stopped validating for empty fields. If a required field is empty it will still submit the form. However, if I test from using the test link it works fine. So I guess there are files missing in the live server to handle this

Comment: But I can't figure out what might be missing in the server. The form submits. It doesn't show any error or exception. This just happens when I host it in IIS in the LIVE Server but not in a test server. Any idea(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I uploaded the application to IIS I uploaded the files in the project solution but left the packages folder out which was in an upper level of the application's parent folder.
So the references for the validations weren't available.
Thanks to all for the replies.